# Unexpected results when using dynamic input in QueryBuilder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access, query-builder

I wrote a SQL query to interact with an MS Access database. Here's the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 
FROM employee 
WHERE ([M-ID] = ?) AND (pnumber NOT IN (
    SELECT pnumber 
    FROM evaluation 
    WHERE ([year] = ?) AND ([month] = ?)
))
```

The query meant to count the number records that are present within `employee` table **and** not present in the `evaluation` with the given conditions.

Problem is when I replace the placeholders with actual input it works correctly. But when placeholders are present (`?`) in the query and VisualStudio prompts for the input it returns different results. I enter the very same input in the prompt dialogue as I did previously in the query but results are different. When parameters are provided statically within the query the result of COUNT is correct but not when provided dynamically via `?` placeholders.

Below are a few screenshots to illustrate the issue.

**Dynamic Input:**
[image: dynamic input dialogue]

**Dynamic Input Results:**
[image: dynamic input results]

**Static Input Results:**
[image: static input results]

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the visual studio query-builder but is it possible to replace the 3 static values one by one with a question mark to see if the problem is due to one specific placeholder?

Comment: I did that. As far as I see the problem is with the combination of all three placeholders. If I remove one of them, no matter which the query will correctly result in 3. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Did you also try the combinations of 2 placeholders and 1 static value? Sorry, all I can do is to think along and at this moment I would guess that the query builder does not map the fields of the pop up to the correct placeholder (since they are all called ? you have no way to know which is the first/second/third in your query.)

Comment: I just reread your last comment and realize you actually already answered my previous question, sorry for missing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wild guess, but based on Access experience back to 2.0: take the hyphen out of the field name.

Comment: Thank you very much Delmer, you saved me a hell of time!